# Ignore file once in git

Tags: django, git, heroku

I'm very much dumb and new in this topic.. I've searched for a clear answer but I didn't find so far. And i'm afraid to ruin my prod server files. So..

I have a server (written in pyhton & Django). I have one file that changes according to the environment (settings.py).

I've 3 Boolean variables for 3 environment
When running on local computer i'm changing this file accordingly, as well as development server and prod server (which both hosted in Heorku).

I'm using `sourcetree` for managing my git.
When i want to test my code in the development server i'm pushing my code from my bitbucket repo 'dev' branch to my heroku git DevServer. but then my `settings.py` is being pushed as well so i need to configure it back to dev server configuration. And then back to local development and then to dev server again and then to prod server - allot of single file pushes that seems to me that i can avoid. When i'm doing merge from development to master, again this `settings.py` file will be changed and i need to update it again to match the production environment.

Make long story short, I would like to avoid that. Once I've put this file in the server I want to ignore it from changes. But putting it in ignore will ignore it always. There are sometimes important changes in the file that I do want to push to all repos/environments..

I've tried not to commit the file, but i'm getting errors that this file need to be committed or discard.

Comment: I suggest you read about `.gitignore` ([man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore))

Comment: In `rails` you have different configurations for dev, testing  and production in the same config files. Thus you don't have this dilemma. You select between with an env variable. You sure that django doesn't have the same?

Comment: good point.. didn't think about this direction :) Check the answer of @Amadan.. using env variables in heroku. works great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commit two versions of the file: `my_site/dev_settings.py` and `my_site/prod_settings.py`

Use [Heroku config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) to change `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to either `my_site.dev_settings` or `my_site.prod_settings`

---

Alternately (and probably a better idea, if the file contains secrets - and it usually does - which should not ever be committed):

Set the changeable or secret values in `settings.py` to environment variables:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('MY_SITE_SECRET_KEY', 'dummy')
DEBUG = os.environ.get('MY_SITE_DEBUG') == 'True'
```

then set `MY_SITE_SECRET_KEY` and `MY_SITE_DEBUG` as Heroku config vars.

---

Finally, the literal answer to your question, though not the path I suggest for your scenario:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree my_site/settings.py
```

will stop Git from noticing changes in your file, till such time you issue

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree my_site/settings.py
```